# Issue: Decoding a file on linux machine from command line

Tags: linux, utf-8, decoding

I have some French codepoints that i would like to decode to utf-8 on a Linux System.
The content of my file is (little example):

`Lemari%C3%A9%20`

Which decoded should be: `Lemarié`

I read that iconv is a great tool for achieving this but i dont know what i should use as `-f` argument, because the file content is encoded, so  am only trying with the `-t` option without success:
`iconv -t UTF8 test.csv`

Any advice?

Comment: What are the percent signs for? That makes it look like URL encoded text or something. If you have URL encoded text in your file then I would expect each percent sign to be treated as an individual character by UTF-8. [Your text above, URL decoded](http://urldecode.org/?decode=Lemari%25C3%25A9%2520) and [The correct UTF-8 byte sequence should be this](http://hexutf8.com/?q=#Lemarié)

Answer (score 1):

From the man page, following is the command to convert input from ISO88592 encoding format to UTF8 encoding format. output would be the output.txt file.

```
iconv -f ISO88592 -t UTF8 < input.txt > output.txt
```

So in your case, `-f` should be used with the encoding format of the input file. Like

```
iconv -f <input file encoding format> -t UTF8 < test.csv > output.txt
```

Comment: thx this was already clear to me, the question is what char encoding to use as `-f` when dealng with encoded strings